# Show that s=supA

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering if my solution is correct

Question: Let $A ⊆ \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and bounded above, let $s\in \mathbb{R}$ have the property that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, s+1/n$ is an upper bound for A. Show that s=sup A.

My solution:

We observe first that, for each $x \in A$ we have

$x \leq s+ \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Hence for each $x \in A$ we have

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (s+ \frac{1}{n}) =s$

Hence we hace $x \leq s$ for all $s \in A$

SO, s is an upper bound for A.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given

Then there is an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$s- \epsilon < s - 1/n_0$ from following the archimedian property.

From the hypothesis, we have $y \in A$ such that $s- 1/n_0 <y$ because $s - 1/n_0$ is not an upper bound for A.

So, we have $s- \epsilon <y$ for some $y \in A$

Hence $s- \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for A.

Since $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary, we have s = sup A

Correct?

Comment: Note that from the conditions as currently stated, we cannot show $s$ is the supremum. It **is** an upper bound.

Comment: You might mean "..show $s\ge\sup A$". Assume the contrary, that $s<\sup A$, let $t=\sup A-s>0$, pick $n>\frac1t$, then $t>\frac1n$ hence $\sup A=s+t>s+\frac1n$, hence $a>s+\frac1n$ for some $a\in A$, a contradiction.

Comment: With an additional condition that s - 1/n is not an upper bound of the set, for all n, s = supA will hold right?

Answer (score 0):

The statement you are trying to prove is incorrect. For example, if $A=(0,1)$, then $s=10$ has the property that $s+\frac1{n}$ is an upper bound for $A$.

However, clearly, $s$ is not the supremum of $A$.

Your proof is false in the sentence:

> From the hypothesis, we have $y\in A$ such that $s-\frac1{n_0}<y$ because $s-\frac{1}{n_0}$ is not an upper bound for $A$.

This is false. Where does your hypothesis tell you that $s-\frac1{n_0}$ is not an upper bound?